# compiled fortran code looks for input parameter file in the incorrect directory

Tags: fortran, executable, command-prompt

I have a compiled fortran 90 code "NewSourceID.exe"in folder E:\TROUBLESHOOT. This uses input file MAIN.IN in the same folder. I use a batch script run_sa.BAT in the same folder E:\TROUBLESHOOT to run this executable. This batch script is generated at run time by another VB code (this is a requirement and cannot be done away with) and the batch script reads as following.

"E:\TROUBLESHOOT\NewSourceID.exe" "E:\TROUBLESHOOT\MAIN.IN".

There are two scenarios
1. When I go to the folder E:\TROUBLESHOOT and double click the batch script run_sa.BAT the NewSourceID.exe runs correctly without any problem. It runs on the command prompt window showing the path C:\WINDOWS\system32\command.exe.

1. When I run the same from the VB script by generating the batch script at runtime I get the following error.

"
C:\Documents and Settings\epsuser\My Documents>"E:\TROUBLESHOOT\NewSourceID.exe"
 "E:\TROUBLESHOOT\MAIN.IN"
forrtl: severe (29): file not found, unit 31, file C:\Documents and Settings\eps
user\My Documents\MAIN.IN

The code tries to find the input file MAIN.IN on the path C:\Documents and Settings\epsuser\My Documents\MAIN.IN which is not the correct path to look for the file.
This happened when I replaced the NewSourceID.exe with a modified one. Earlier the code used to run correctly even from the VB with the following path. C:\WINDOWS\system32\command.exe -E:\TROUBLESHOOT\run_sa.BAT. How can this be done?

Comment: You should show us the code, how the fortran exe gets the file name, otherwise we cannot know, Aradi's answer will be sufficient for you. Or just accept his answer.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure, the Fortran program NewSourceID reads the command line argument you pass to it? Especially older Fortran programs (before Fortran 2003) had no standard way to parse command line arguments. I guess, the name `MAIN.IN` is hardwired in the code you use, and it always uses the `MAIN.IN` file from the *current directory*. You could work around this by issuing a change directory command before executing the program. I am not very familiar with Windows, but something like

```
cd E:\TROUBLESHOOT
E:\TROUBLESHOOT\NewSourceID.exe
```

in your batch script would probably work.

Alternatively, you could implement proper command line argument parsing in your Fortran code, using the `command_argument_count()` and `get_command_argument()` functions. You would need a Fortran 2003 compiler for that.

Comment: There are no Fortran 2003 compilers (even though some may claim to be), but a Fortran 95 with this extension will suffice. Also, older Fortran compilers used to use `GETARG` intrinsic as an extension for this job.